# Access parent DIV of user-control (ascx) from its code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

From within the code-behind of an ASP .NET web user-control (`ascx`) I need to get access (at runtime) to its parent, a div element. The aim is simple as to modify the visibility of the mentioned parent div.

I can not touch so much of the web-page code so I'd need a solution requiring only modifications in the user-control's code behind.

So in the HTML "part" of the code of the  web page I have this:

```
<div id="parentDIV" runat="server">
    <uc:MyUserControl ID="myUserControlInstance" runat="server" />
</div>
```

I'd like to do in the code behind of the user-control something like this:

```
this.Container.Visible = false;
```

Note that I'm not asking if it is a good practise or not to do this.

**EDIT:**
The user-control code behind does not "know" about the ID of the parent DIV.

Comment: can you use the scriptmanager class to run some jquery in the code behind?

Comment: Yes, I can. Post it as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hide it on the client.  Decorate your user control container (div?) with a class like "awesomeUserControl". Then emit some javascript using the ScriptManager object to hide the parent like this:

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "HideMyAwesomeUserControl", "$('.awesomeUserControl').parent().hide();", true);

Comment: I decided to use this approach, slightly modified for my needs. In my concrete scenario the user control's top level element is a server `div` control, with ID let's say `divUserControl`, so finally my code looks like this: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(MyUserControl), "someScriptKey", "$('" + this.divUserControl.ClientID + "').parent('div').addClass('non-display');", true);`. This suits this concrete need. The other solutions required that the user-control would have known about the name/id in one case, or the concrete type of parent, on the other case.

Answer (score 1):

**The better way...**

What you should do is to create a custom event in your user control, to which your container will subscribe - very much like subscribing to a button event, only this is your custom control.  This event passes information to your container which can then discern from it what it needs, such as whether or not the div should/not be visible.

It might look something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.myuserControl.Update += new MyUserControlUpdateEventHandler(myuserControl_Update);
}

void myuserControl_Update(object sender, MyuserControlEventArgs e)
{
    this.parentDiv.visible = !e.ShouldHideUI;
}
```

This method will decouple your parent with the user control, i.e. your user control doesn't have to have any knowledge at all of the parent's controls, nor should it.

If you are curious, here is a ***rough*** example of how your user control will define such an event:

```
public class MyuserControlEventArgs : EventArgs 
{
    public bool ShouldHideUI { get;set;}
    public MyuserControlEventArgs (bool shouldHideUI) 
    {
         this.ShouldHideUI = shouldHideUI;
    }
}
public delegate void MyUserControlUpdateEventHandler(object sender, MyuserControlEventArgs e);
public event MyUserControlUpdateEventHandler Update;
protected void OnUpdate(MyuserControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (Update!= null)
        Update(this, e);
}
```

Your user control will simply need to call OnUpdate whenever it feels its subscribers need to know about it.

**The Quick and Dirty way...**

If you need quick and dirty, then try this (inside your user control):

```
TheParentControl parentControl = (TheParentControl)this.Parent;
parentControl.ParentDiv.Visible = true;
```

The key is to *cast to the appropriate type* (apparently your user control would know what type of parent it has), then set the parent's property.  You might expose your div as a property in the parent control.  Note, that parent could be ANY control (page, FooControl, BarControl, whatever) whose control collection your user control resides. Once you get a handle to the parent, you can even `FindControl()` to find a control by name.

Comment: Nice but not in my situation, I must figure out something can be done just in the user-control's code behind.

Comment: Updated answer.  Skip to end.

Comment: I would like to avoid doing that as the control is hosted by different  pages (of different types). So as happens with the answer provided by @Kanavi I'd wait for other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there....

```
this.Parent.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Nop, this.Parent, in runtine is the form.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking `this.Parent` in the right context? At what stage are you checking it?

Answer (score 0):

When all controls get rendered, the `HTML` Parent child controls can be determined like below.

I am using while loop, so in case you add some other intermediate control, it may not give crash or unexpected results.

```
public Control ParentControl
{
    get
    {
        Control ctl = this.Parent;
        while (true)
        {
            if (ctl == null) break;
            if (ctl.ID.Equals("parentDIV"))
            {
                break;
            }
            ctl = ctl.Parent;
        }
        return ctl;
    }
}

if(ParentControl != null)
    ParentControl.Visible = true|false;
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the name of the of parent div in runtime within the user-control's code behind, and I cannot modify the web page to pass it to the control.

Comment: But you mentioned the Parent Div with it's ID.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've edited my post to remark that though I put that sample name in the HTML code the user-control does not know about its container name.

Comment: That means the User control is circumscribed with this Div ParentDiv. Right? Now, Please check the above property mentioned.

Comment: That user control is used repeatedly wide along the web-app, and I don't know all the IDs of all the different containers that might be wrapping this user control.

Comment: Of course I could recover the different names and put them inside the `while` loop but I'd prefer to not need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, it sounds like you have a usercontrol and an aspx page (both have code behind's).
The user control appears to have been added to the aspx page, wrapped in a div. YOu've made the div control runat server (though you can still do this via htmlcontrol).
All you ned to do to manage the div is:

parentDIV.visible = false;

or whatever you need to do with the div.

Why does the UC code behind need to know about the APSX pages DIV, it doesn't.